# Dropdown bug - Next JS and Tailwind

Tags: node.js, tailwind-css

Hello Stack Overflow friends. I wanted you to help me fix a bug I have in this dropdown. When I open it, all the components at the bottom move, and what I want is for the menu to overlap the layout. Here is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BiChevronsDown } from "react-icons/bi";
import { AiOutlineSearch } from "react-icons/ai";

const Selector = () => {
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState(null);
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://restcountries.com/v2/all?field=name')
        .then(res=> res.json())
        .then(data=> {
            setCountries(data);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="w-72 font-medium text-sm">
            <div 
                onClick={ () => setOpen(!open) } 
                className={`bg-white w-full p-2 flex items-center justify-between rounded border-2 border-dark-blue ${ !selected && "text-gray-700"}`}
            >
                {selected 
                    ? selected?.length > 25 
                        ? selected?.substring(0, 25)  + "..."
                        : selected
                : "Escoge el pais"}
                <BiChevronsDown size={20} className={`${open && "rotate-180"}`}/>
            </div>
            <ul className={`bg-white mt-2 overflow-y-auto rounded ${open ? 'max-h-60 border-2 border-dark-blue ' : 'max-h-0'}`}>
                <div className="flex items-center p-2 sticky top-0 bg-white">
                    <AiOutlineSearch size={18} className="text-gray-700"/>
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        value={inputValue}
                        onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value.toUpperCase())}
                        placeholder="Selecciona el país" 
                        className="placeholder:text-gray-700 outline-none"
                    />
                </div>
                {countries?.map((country) => (
                    <li 
                        key={country?.name}
                        className={`p-2 hover:bg-sky-600 hover:text-white 
                        
                        ${country?.name?.toUpperCase() === selected?.toUpperCase() &&
                            'bg-sky-600 text-white'
                        }

                        ${country?.name?.toUpperCase().startsWith(inputValue) 
                            ? "block"
                            : "hidden"
                        }`}

                        onClick={() => {
                            if(country?.name?.toUpperCase() !== selected.toUpperCase()){
                                setSelected(country?.name);
                                setOpen(false);
                                setInputValue("");
                            }
                        }}
                    >
                        {country?.name}
                    </li>
                ))}    
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Selector;
```

I tried to make it absolute and it worked, but the dropdown stays static on the screen when doing this and mixes with the components at the bottom.